# Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

The code is

main.js

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import render from 'react-dom'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose, bindActionCreators} from 'redux'
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux'
import ReduxPromise from 'redux-promise'
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk'

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
import rootReducer from './src/reducers'
import App from './src/containers/App'

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware),
    window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f
  )
);


ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
)
```

app.js

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react'
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import Header from '../components/Header'
import MainSection from '../components/MainSection'
import * as TodoActions from '../actions'

const App = ({todos, actions}) => (
    <div>
        <Header addTodo={actions.addTodo}></Header>
        <MainSection todos={todos} actions={actions} />
    </div>
)
App.propTypes = {
    todos: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    actions: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

const mapStateTypes = state => ({
    todos: state.todos
})

const mapDispathToProps = dispatch => ({
    actions: bindActionCreators(TodoActions, dispatch)
})

export default connect(mapStateTypes, mapDispathToProps)(App)
```

MainSection.js

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react'
import TodoItem from './TodoItem'

export default class MainSection extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
    }
    componentDidMount(){
    }
    render(){
        const todos = this.props.todos;
        const actions = this.props.actions

        return (
            <section className="main">
                <ul className="todo-list">
                    {todos.map((todo) => {
                        return (<TodoItem todo={todo} key={todo.id} {...actions} actions = {actions}/>)
                    })}
                </ul>
            </section>
        )
    }
}
```

TodoItem.js

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react'

export default class TodoItem extends Component{
    static propTypes = {
        todo: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        deleteTodo: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    }

    handleDelete = () => {
        const todo = this.props;
        let deleteTodo = this.props.actions.deleteTodo;
        this.props.deleteTodo(todo.id)
    }
    handleChange =  () => {

    }
    render(){
        console.log(this.props)
        const {todo, deleteTodo} = this.props;
        let elem;
        elem = (
            <div className="views">
                <input type="checkbox" className="toggle" defaultChecked={todo.completed} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                <label>{todo.text}</label>
                <button className="destory" onClick ={this.handleDelete}></button>
            </div>
        )

        return(
            <li className="editing">{elem}</li>
        )
    }
}
```

when I clicked the delete button , there is error

I know the problem is in this line `this.props.deleteTodo(todo.id)`

but I donot know why   and  how to fix

I tried the answer at same question, but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Looks like redux-thunk is not working in this case and that is because there is something wrong with your `applyMiddleware`.

From the docs if you see you need to pass `thunk` to the applyMiddleWare.

```
// Note: this API requires redux@>=3.1.0
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
);
```

But you are passing `thunkMiddleware`

```
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware), //should be thunk
    window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f
  )
);
```

Check out the docs [here](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have wrong architecture. I've noticed that you use thunk + redux. But you don't use connect() to wrap your components with react redux. To use connect you need to import it with `import {connect} from 'react-redux'`

In your components when you want to delete an item you should dispatch action creator with action DELETE_ITEM or any other and id of the element that you need to delete.

Action creator should emit action "DELETE_ITEM". It can be async because you use thunk middleware which enables you to use functions.
Then it should delete item and emit action DELETED_ITEM (action names can be different)

deleteReducer should take care of this action and when DELETED_ITEM action is performed it should update the store.

In your component, you need to add

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        deletedItem: state.deleteReducer.item
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
           onDeleteClick: () => {
                dispatch(actions.deleteItem()) // deleteItem is action creator
        }
    }

}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(TodoItem);
```

After that in your state, you will have deleted item and you can do something with it and you will be able to dispatch action on click in your Todo Component by using

```
this.props.onDeleteClick();
```

If I were you I'd start with [learning how redux flow works](https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux)

Comment: but you connected app component and you should connect Todo component instead